# How can I access req.file without multer?

Tags: node.js, express

I dont want to use multer (or the memory/disk storage). I want get the buffer from my body and send it directly to cloudinary with upload_stream but if I want to access my files with form-data I get req.file undefined. What I am doing wrong ? Should I change the content-type ?

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/api/upload/images', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    console.log(req.files);
   return res.send('x');
});
```

Comment: To get that buffer you need to parse incoming request body,  which has `multipart/form-data` content-type. That what `multer` and other libraries do, without it its not possible unless you send that file in different format like base64 encoded string (overhead is more since baset64 increases request size by ~33% and slow).

Comment: So I should use multer ? But I want to stream the incoming request to my cloudinary so when I use multer and  memory storage then it can slow down my app or do I have misunderstand something ?

Comment: Then you better use [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy), multer internally uses busboy to parse formdata.  check 2nd example [snippet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy). It emits [file event](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy) containing readable stream of that file's data.